# Открытие и чтение файла, запись в файл

Tags: python

Помогите решить задачку.

У меня есть файл с данными:

```
Омлет
3
Яйцо | 2 | шт
Молоко | 100 | мл
Помидор | 2 | шт

Утка по-пекински
4
Утка | 1 | шт
Вода | 2 | л
Мед | 3 | ст.л
Соевый соус | 60 | мл

Запеченный картофель
3
Картофель | 1 | кг
Чеснок | 3 | зубч
Сыр гауда | 100 | г

Фахитос
5
Говядина | 500 | г
Перец сладкий | 1 | шт
Лаваш | 2 | шт
Винный уксус | 1 | ст.л
Помидор | 2 | шт
```

Его нужно привести к:

```
cook_book = {
  'Омлет': [
    {'ingridient_name': 'Яйцо', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'шт.'},
    {'ingridient_name': 'Молоко', 'quantity': 100, 'measure': 'мл'},
    {'ingridient_name': 'Помидор', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'шт'}
    ],
  'Утка по-пекински': [
    {'ingridient_name': 'Утка', 'quantity': 1, 'measure': 'шт'},
    {'ingridient_name': 'Вода', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'л'},
    {'ingridient_name': 'Мед', 'quantity': 3, 'measure': 'ст.л'},
    {'ingridient_name': 'Соевый соус', 'quantity': 60, 'measure': 'мл'}
    ],
  'Запеченный картофель': [
    {'ingridient_name': 'Картофель', 'quantity': 1, 'measure': 'кг'},
    {'ingridient_name': 'Помидор', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'шт'},
    {'ingridient_name': 'Сыр гауда', 'quantity': 100, 'measure': 'г'},
    ]
  }
```

Мой код:

```
cook_book_dict = dict()
cook_book_ingredients_list = list()
with open('dishes_list.txt', encoding="utf - 8") as f:
    for line in f:
        del cook_book_ingredients_list[:]
        dish_name = line.strip()
        s = int(f.readline().strip())
        while s != 0:
            string = f.readline().strip()
            line_ingr= string.split("|")
            cook_book_ingredients_list.append({''[{'ingridient_name': line_ingr[0].strip(), 'quantity': line_ingr[1].strip(),'measure': line_ingr[2].strip()}]})
            print(cook_book_ingredients_list)
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

У меня это слабая тема, не могу никак разобраться(

Comment: Перед уткой идет:
 Омлет 3 Яйцо | 2 | шт Молоко | 100 | мл Помидор | 2 | шт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import json

keys = ['ingridient_name', 'quantity', 'measure', ]
with open('dishes_list.txt') as text:
    lines = filter(bool, map(str.strip, text))
    cook_book_dict = {n: [{k: v for (k, v) in zip(keys, map(str.strip, next(lines).split(' | ', 2)))}
                          for _ in range(int(next(lines)))] for n in lines}
print(json.dumps(cook_book_dict, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

особо не знаю что тут пояснять, просто разверну

```
import json

keys = ['ingridient_name', 'quantity', 'measure', ]
cook_book_dict = {}

with open('dishes_list.txt') as text:
    # только непустые линии
    lines = []
    for line in text:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            lines.append(line)
        continue
    lines = iter(lines)  # https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter

    # далее выталкиваем текст из iter
    for name in lines:  # шаг_1 - вытолкнутая тут линия - всегда блюдо
        cook_book_dict[name] = []
        num = next(lines)  # шаг_2 - следующая за блюдом - всегда номер

        for _ in range(int(num)):  # шаг_3 - затем надо вытолкнуть из iter - num линий состава блюда
            sostav_line = next(lines)  # одна из линий состава
            ingrid = sostav_line.split(' | ')  # разбить на ингридиенты
            z = zip(keys, ingrid)  # сопоставить ключ - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip
            sostav_dict = {k: v for (k, v) in z}  # генератор словаря ингридиентов
            cook_book_dict[name].append(sostav_dict)
            continue

        # тк все линии не пустые, и мы вытолкнули все линии текущего юляда, следующая лиция опять будет - блюдо
        continue

print(json.dumps(cook_book_dict, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Comment: import json

keys = ['ingridient_name', 'quantity', 'measure', ]
with open('dishes_list.txt') as text:
    lines = filter(bool, map(str.strip, text))
    cook_book_dict = {n: [{k: v for (k, v) in zip(keys, map(str.strip, next(lines).split(' | ', 2)))}
                          for _ in range(int(next(lines)))] for n in lines}
print(json.dumps(cook_book_dict, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))

Не могли бы вы немного пояснить код?

Comment: особо не знаю что тут пояснять, просто разверну

Answer (score 4):

```
import re

with open('dishes_list.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.read()

def parse_block(block):
    name, _, data = block.partition('\n')
    data = re.findall(r'[\r\n]([^\r\n\d]*)\s+\|\s*(\d+)\s+\|\s*([^\r\n\|]*)', data)
    return {name:[dict(ingridient_name=tup[0],
                       quantity=int(tup[1]),
                       measure=tup[2])]
                  for tup in data}

res = {name:data for block in text.split('\n\n')
       for name, data in parse_block(block).items()}
```

результат:

```
{'Омлет': [{'ingridient_name': 'Помидор', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'шт'}],
 'Утка по-пекински': [{'ingridient_name': 'Соевый соус',
   'quantity': 60,
   'measure': 'мл'}],
 'Запеченный картофель': [{'ingridient_name': 'Сыр гауда',
   'quantity': 100,
   'measure': 'г'}],
 'Фахитос': [{'ingridient_name': 'Помидор', 'quantity': 2, 'measure': 'шт'}]}
```